# Whether to choose "and" or "or"?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, terminology, coordination

> The maximum length of a file name is 12 characters. Incremental and date-and-time suffixes that are separated by # [which word to use here: **and** or **or**?]  @ are not subject to this restriction and can exceed the 12-character limit.
>
> ```
> abcdefgh.txt                 - OK
> abcdefgh.txt#2               - OK
> abcdefgh.txt@20110228t1359   - OK
> abcdefgh.txt@20110228t1359#2 - OK
> abcdefghijklmopqrs.txt       - wrong
> ```

This is an excerpt from the manual I am working on. My question is whether I should use **and** or **or** in the second sentence.

I suppose it will be ambiguous in either case, but I would to stick to the practice that have a wider use and clearer meaning.

Comment: "And" would imply that both characters should be used together:  `abcdefgh.txt@#20110228t1359`

Comment: Since **either** character allows for longer file names, the word is **or**, and it is not ambiguous. *Respectively* does not fit here because there is no parallel like: "# or @ allow for longer lengths of 20 and 22 respectively," meaning that # allows 20, @ allows 22.

Comment: Thanks, Yosef. A note for other readers: I have suggested to use "respectively" after @.

Comment: I think you mean that you had suggested *respectively*, but deleted it as unneeded. Your comment of "have suggested" sounds like you now make that recommendation.

Comment: Yes, sorry; I had suggested _respectively_, but deleted it as unneeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your technicalities are clear and are secondary to the main issue of the logic of use of *and* and *or*.

“... are separated by # and @ ...” implies that the separation is effected by using both characters. This clearly does not apply to your examples so should not be used.

“ ... by # or @ ...“ means one or the other (the exclusive or) or may mean both (the inclusive or). This is consistent with your examples so is the correct one to use.

Another point to notice is that you define the 12 character limit to apply to *title*. Confusingly, you then refer to ***the*** 12 character limit in relation to the *suffixes*. You might better refer to the suffixes as being able to exceed *any such* 12 character limit, or *any such* limit.

Comment: I'm "non-technical" because I'm retired after 45 years in the computer industry?

Comment: This is userist. I close-voted for a language-based reason. 'Or' certainly works, as one would hope almost every native speaker would appreciate; 'and' is ambiguous (which ambiguity has [been covered on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488202/made-with-a-and-b-exclusive) before) (and which you miss).

Comment: My apologies to both. Pure supposition on my part based on over-sensitivity from previous experiences. Corrected answer accordingly.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure that I understand your idea about using **any such**. Here is an example filename: `stem.ext@suffix`. My idea is that `stem.ext` is limited to 12 characters and `@suffix` can have arbitrary length. That is, the 12-character limit is applied to pre-@-or-# part a filename, and there are no other limits. And therefore, using "any such" does not make sense to me because it implies that there are multiple 12-character limits, and this assumption is not correct.